# Sorting Visualizer in React

Tags: react.js, jsx

I just started learning React for a university project to make an algorithms visualizer. I need a review of my code below for visualizing selection sort.
I would also appreciate suggestion on how to make it more extensible : I want to add other sorts (bubble, insertion, quick and merge) as well, so nesting all of them in the SortingVisualizer component would make it look terrible and hard to manage.

````javascript
import {useRef, useState} from 'react';


const normalBarColor = 'red';
const modifiedBarColor = 'green';
const containerColor = 'black';
const beingComparedColor = 'yellow';
const beingSwappedColor = 'white';
const settledColor = 'orange';

function ArrayBar(props) {
    const scalingFactor = 100;
    const value = props.value;
    const color = props.color;
    const style = {
        backgroundColor: color,
        height: `${value * scalingFactor}px`,
        width: '10px',
        margin: `10px`
    };
    return <div className='arrayBar' style={style}></div>
}


function ArrayContainer(props) {
    const arrayBars = props.arrayBars;
    const style = {
        backgroundColor: containerColor,
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
        height: '800px',
        width: '800px',
    }
    return <div style={style}>
        {arrayBars.map((bar, i) => <ArrayBar key={i} value={bar.value} color={bar.color}/>)}
    </div>;
}

function SelectionSortButton(props) {
    const onClickHandler = props.onClick;
    return <div>
        <button onClick={onClickHandler}>Sort</button>
    </div>
}


export default function SortingVisualizer() {
    const dataInit = [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1];
    const arrayBarsInit = [];
    const COMPARE = 1;
    const SWAP = 2;
    const DO_NOTHING = 3;
    for (let i = 0; i < dataInit.length; i++) {
        arrayBarsInit.push({value: dataInit[i], color: normalBarColor});
    }

    const [arrayBars, setArrayBars] = useState(arrayBarsInit);
    const iRef = useRef(0);
    const jRef = useRef(iRef.current + 1);
    const minIndexRef = useRef(0);
    const actionRef = useRef(COMPARE);

    function modifyArrayBars(newArrayBars) {
        const arrayBarsCopy = [...newArrayBars];
        setArrayBars(arrayBarsCopy);
    }

    function handleNextSelectionStepClick() {
        selectionSort(arrayBars);
    }

    async function selectionSort(arrayBars) {
        const newArrayBars = [...arrayBars];
        const N = arrayBars.length;

        // compare or swap?
        if (actionRef.current === COMPARE) {
            console.log("comparing ", minIndexRef.current, jRef.current);
            const initialMinIndex = minIndexRef.current;
            const initialJ = jRef.current;
            newArrayBars[jRef.current].color = beingComparedColor;
            newArrayBars[minIndexRef.current].color = beingComparedColor;

            modifyArrayBars(newArrayBars);

            if (newArrayBars[jRef.current].value < newArrayBars[minIndexRef.current].value) {
                minIndexRef.current = jRef.current;
            }

            await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 200));

            jRef.current += 1;
            if (jRef.current === N) {
                actionRef.current = SWAP;
            }

            newArrayBars[initialJ].color = normalBarColor;
            newArrayBars[initialMinIndex].color = normalBarColor;
            modifyArrayBars(newArrayBars);
        } else if (actionRef.current === SWAP) {
            newArrayBars[minIndexRef.current].color = beingSwappedColor;
            newArrayBars[iRef.current].color = beingSwappedColor;

            modifyArrayBars(newArrayBars);

            await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 200));

            const temp = newArrayBars[iRef.current];
            newArrayBars[iRef.current] = newArrayBars[minIndexRef.current];
            newArrayBars[minIndexRef.current] = temp;

            newArrayBars[minIndexRef.current].color = normalBarColor;
            newArrayBars[iRef.current].color = settledColor;
            modifyArrayBars(newArrayBars);

            iRef.current += 1;
            minIndexRef.current = iRef.current;
            console.log('iRef.current = ', iRef.current);
            jRef.current = iRef.current < N - 1 ? iRef.current + 1 : iRef.current;
            if (iRef.current === N) {
                actionRef.current = DO_NOTHING;
            } else {
                actionRef.current = COMPARE;
            }
        } else if (actionRef.current === DO_NOTHING) {

        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <ArrayContainer arrayBars={arrayBars} modifyArrayBars={modifyArrayBars}></ArrayContainer>
            <SelectionSortButton onClick={handleNextSelectionStepClick}></SelectionSortButton>
        </div>
    );
}
```
````

Comment: Your `selectionSort` does two things: sort + display. Consider defining an API (or data structure) that lets each sort algorithm **report** its actions, like compare / swap indexes `i` & `j`, rather than display its actions. Then you can have a sorter and a new display routine that each do just [one thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). And the quicksort you add in future will be smaller and easier to write. Reports could go to a basic display, and perhaps to a fancier UI that lets you scroll forward & backward in time. Or show stacked display of two reports.

Answer (score 2):

## Things I love about the code:

- Your components are small.
- Your use of design tokens. (normalBarColor, modifiedBarColor, containerColor…)
- You have a clear separation between your js and jsx.

## Issues found:

```
function ArrayContainer(props) {
    ...
    {arrayBars.map((bar, i) => <ArrayBar key={i} value={bar.value} color={bar.color}/>)}
    ...
}
```

Avoid using index (i) as a key.  See: [why-does-react-need-keys](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#why-does-react-need-keys). tldr; better performance

```
function SelectionSortButton(props) {
    const onClickHandler = props.onClick;
    return <div>
        <button onClick={onClickHandler}>Sort</button>
    </div>
}
```

This component doesn’t do anything, consider removing

```
export default function SortingVisualizer() {
...
        // prefer dataInit.map over for ()
        for (let i = 0; i < dataInit.length; i++) {
        // prefer immutable (avoid push) 
        arrayBarsInit.push({value: dataInit[i], color: normalBarColor});
    }
...
                                // this seems to block the render process
                                // Never block the render process.  
                await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 200));
...
    // ArrayContainer ignores modifyArrayBars
   <ArrayContainer arrayBars={arrayBars} modifyArrayBars={modifyArrayBars}></ArrayContainer>
```

I was unable to follow your logic in SortingVisualizer.  I’ve documented some code smells.  You are doing too much in  handleNextSelectionStepClick > selectionSort.  This is a sign you have not found your minimal state.  (See:  [Find minimal state](https://react.dev/learn/thinking-in-react#step-3-find-the-minimal-but-complete-representation-of-ui-state))

## My Versions

Here is my version of Visual sort.  I hope you can update it to meet your needs:

https://codesandbox.io/s/sorting-visualizer-in-react-r86mos

```
import { useState } from "react";

const activeBarColor = "yellow";
const normalBarColor = "red";
const modifiedBarColor = "green";
const containerColor = "black";

// Anything that can be moved out of functions should be moved outside a functions
const SCALING_FACTOR = 100;

// I've modified ArrayBar to take one property "bar", bar holds data about the bar (no longer
// color) and ArrayBar renders based on that data.   Separating values and presentation is a
// good practice.
function ArrayBar(props) {
  const { value, isSorted, isLast } = props.bar;
  const sortedColor = isLast ? activeBarColor : modifiedBarColor;
  const color = isSorted ? sortedColor : normalBarColor;
  const style = {
    backgroundColor: color,
    height: `${value * SCALING_FACTOR}px`,
    width: "10px",
    margin: `10px`,
  };
  return <div className="arrayBar" style={style}></div>;
}

function ArrayContainer(props) {
  const arrayBars = props.arrayBars;
  const style = {
    backgroundColor: containerColor,
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    height: "800px",
    width: "800px",
  };
  // notice we are using bar.value for the key.  We can do that as long
  // as values are unique.
  return (
    <div style={style}>
      {arrayBars.map((bar) => (
        <ArrayBar key={bar.value} bar={bar} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

// I've added some unique values to make the sort more interesting
const DATA_INIT = [7, 6, 5, 6.6, 2.1, 4, 3, 2, 1];
const sortByValue = (a, b) => (a.value > b.value ? 1 : -1);

export default function SortingVisualizer() {
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
  const handleNextSelectionStepClick = () => {
    setStep((oldIndex) => oldIndex + 1);
  };
  const sortedArray = DATA_INIT.filter((v, i) => i <= step) // filter out unsorted
    .map((value, i) => ({ value, isSorted: true, isLast: i === step })) // transform value to bar object
    .sort(sortByValue);

  const unsortedArray = DATA_INIT.filter((v, i) => i > step) // filter out sorted
    .map((value) => ({ value })); // transform value to bar object

  const arrayBars = [...sortedArray, ...unsortedArray];  // concatenate the two array

  return (
    <div>
      <ArrayContainer arrayBars={arrayBars}></ArrayContainer>
      <button onClick={handleNextSelectionStepClick}>Sort</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Second iteration using styled components and a second sort.  I wish I could help more with showing more real sort algorithms, but it's been 30 years since I took that course.
https://codesandbox.io/s/sorting-visualizer-in-react-2-t2wnht

```
import { useState } from "react";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";
const activeBarColor = "yellow";
const normalBarColor = "red";
const modifiedBarColor = "green";
const containerColor = "black";
const nextColor = "lime";

// Anything that can be moved out of functions should be moved outside a 
// functions
const SCALING_FACTOR = 50;

const ArrayBar = styled.div((props) => {
  const { value, isSorted, isLast, isNext } = props.bar;
  const sortedColor = isLast ? activeBarColor : modifiedBarColor;
  const unsortedColor = isNext ? nextColor : normalBarColor;
  const color = isSorted ? sortedColor : unsortedColor;

  return css`
    background-color: ${color};
    height: ${value * SCALING_FACTOR}px;
    width: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
  `;
});

const Container = styled.div`
  background-color: ${containerColor};
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 400px;
  width: 800px;
`;

function ArrayContainer(props) {
  const arrayBars = props.arrayBars;
  // notice we are using bar.value for the key.  We can do that as long
  // as values are unique.
  return (
    <Container>
      {arrayBars.map((bar) => (
        <ArrayBar key={bar.value} bar={bar} />
      ))}
    </Container>
  );
}

// I've added some unique values to make the sort more interesting
const DATA_INIT = [7, 6, 5, 6.6, 2.1, 4, 3, 2, 1];
const sortByValue = (a, b) => (a.value > b.value ? 1 : -1);
const initSorted = [...DATA_INIT].sort();

const otherSort = (step) => {
  const sortedArray = initSorted.filter((v, i) => i <= step); // filter out unsorted
  const sortedOjbectArray = sortedArray.map((value, i) => ({
    value,
    isSorted: true,
    isLast: i === step
  })); // transform value to bar object

  const unsortedArray = DATA_INIT.filter(
    (value) => !sortedArray.includes(value)
  ) // filter out sorted
    .map((value) => ({ value, isNext: initSorted[step + 1] === value })); // transform value to bar object

  console.log({ unsortedArray });

  return [...sortedOjbectArray, ...unsortedArray]; // concatenate the two array
};

const insertionLikeSort = (step) => {
  const sortedArray = DATA_INIT.filter((v, i) => i <= step) // filter out unsorted
    .map((value, i) => ({ value, isSorted: true, isLast: i === step })) // transform value to bar object
    .sort(sortByValue);

  const unsortedArray = DATA_INIT.filter((v, i) => i > step) // filter out sorted
    .map((value, i) => ({ value, isNext: i === 0 })); // transform value to bar object

  return [...sortedArray, ...unsortedArray]; // concatenate the two array
};

export default function SortingVisualizer() {
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0);
  const handleNextSelectionStepClick = () => {
    setStep((oldIndex) => oldIndex + 1);
  };
  const otherBars = otherSort(step);
  const insertBars = insertionLikeSort(step);

  return (
    <div>
      <ArrayContainer arrayBars={insertBars}></ArrayContainer>
      <button onClick={handleNextSelectionStepClick}>Sort</button>
      <ArrayContainer arrayBars={otherBars}></ArrayContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Other thoughts:

- This may be obvious, but put each component into a separate file.  (You probably knew this).
- Be sure to use a linter.  It can catch many common issues.
- Look into [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/docs)